# What is the C# equivalent of this syntax?

Tags: c#, typescript

Can anyone tell me what is the c# equivalent of this property declaration?

```
filters: { [arg: string]: string };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent syntax in the sense you can't really use an object as a dictionary in C#. There is a dedicated dictionary class you can use instead:

```cs
Dictionary<string, string> filters;
```

Comment: Technically, you could use a dynamic object, but this seems to be what he's after.

Comment: Thank you. Another question then, when & why would we use the above syntax rather than this: 
`export interface Filter{
  [key: string]: string;
}`